# How can logstash identify and parse the newly created logfiles?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-file

I'm new in ELK and currently I'm facing the following issue.
I want logstash to parse some server logfiles. Everyday, a new logfile is created which it has the following naming format: file160629.log (where 160629=current date)
Here's my config input:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\LogFiles\u_ex%d.log"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
```

But as it seems, it doesn't recognize the new logfiles..
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the log files inside LogFiles folder you can use :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\LogFiles\*.log"
    }
}
```

It will tail files by default.

Comment: Thank you @PuRaK for your answer. Just for clarification; this way, will start parsing all the logfiles that are already in the folder, or it will start parsing the starting from the newest one?

Comment: It would have already parsed the older ones. It won't parse them again. It will only parse the newer one.

Comment: Read this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path

Comment: Changing the path glob will actually reread all files that match that glob, "Thus, changing the filename patterns will result in a new sincedb file being used and any existing current position state will be lost." https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files